# Kendo grid with button in title to access data

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to have a button in the header bar of a kendo grid. This button needs to be able to call a function (GetFoo) in the grid object.

UPDATE: Sorry for any confusion, but I only want one button on the table header row with the text "First Name", "Last Name" etc... So we'd have

---

[th]|First Name | Last Name | Title | button (calls getFoo())

---

[td]|Joe        |Schmo      |None   |

[td]|Joe       | Bob        |None   |

[End update]

Here is some modified code from kendo ui

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      pageSize: 20,
      data: createRandomData(50)
    },
    getFoo:function(){ 
      alert('bar');
    },
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    columns: [
      { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "140px" },
      { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "140px" },
      { field: "Title" },
      { field: '',title: "<button onClick='getFoo()' value='foo'>sdf</button>" }]
    }).data("kendoGrid");
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should insert your button into the header using the grid's dataBound event.

Comment: Haven't really used dataBound much. If you can provide an example on how this would solve issue, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the dataBound event and insert the button like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
dataSource: {
  pageSize: 20,
  data: createRandomData(50)
},
getFoo:function(){ 
  alert('bar');
},
pageable: true,
height: 550,
dataBound: grid_dataBound,
columns: [
  { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "140px" },
  { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "140px" },
  { field: "Title" },
  { field: '',title: "<button onClick='getFoo()' value='foo'>sdf</button>" }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
});

function grid_dataBound(e) {
var grid = this;

var lastHeaderCell = grid.thead.find("th").last();
var button = $("<button value='foo'>sdf</button>");
lastHeaderCell.html(button);
$(button).click(function(){
    grid.options.getFoo();
});
}
```

Comment: Tried using your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ffa1fqo8/

It gives error grid.getFoo is not a function

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to add custom buttons in a Kendo grid. One would be to add it as a toolbar item. You can read more about the implementation here [Kendo custom command button in toolbars](http://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-command-button-in-toolbars)

```
.ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Template("<a class='k-button k-button-icontext' onclick='customCommand()' href='#'></span>Cutom Command</a>"))
```

Next would be to have one inline per row. You can read how to implement that one here [Kendo grid custom commands](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command)

But the code you want to pay attention to:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                       pageSize: 20,
                       data: createRandomData(50)
                    },
                    pageable: true,
                    height: 550,
                    columns: [
                        { field: "FirstName", title: "First Name", width: "140px" },
                        { field: "LastName", title: "Last Name", width: "140px" },
                        { field: "Title" },
                        { command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }, title: " ", width: "180px" }]
                }).data("kendoGrid");

                wnd = $("#details")
                    .kendoWindow({
                        title: "Customer Details",
                        modal: true,
                        visible: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 300
                    }).data("kendoWindow");

                detailsTemplate = kendo.template($("#template").html());
            });
```

More so this line:

```
{ command: { text: "View Details", click: showDetails }
```

You can also use templates to customize Kendo grids. Check out this link to read more: [Toolbar using templates](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/toolbar-template)

Hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I only want 1 button in the very first table header row, and not on each individual row.

Comment: The first part of the solution above is for a single button on the grid, and you can see an actual demo by clicking the link [DEMO](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/toolbar-template) . In that example they are using the dropdown, but you could use a button.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a Kendo template to achieve this.

in your JavaScript change that line to:

```
{ field: " " title: " ", template: kendo.template($("#button-template").html()) }
```

And in your HTML markup add:

```
<script id="button-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <button type="button" onClick='getFoo()' value='foo'>
        Button Action
    </button>
</script>
```

Or, here is how you can add a single button to the header of your grid:

Create your kendo template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="GridToolbar">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <button type="button"  onClick='getFoo()' value='foo'>Button Action</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Set this property on your kendo grid in JS:

```
toolbar: kendo.template($("#GridToolbar").html()),
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I only want 1 button in the very first table header row, and not on each individual row.

Comment: Updated, my answer. If I am understanding you correctly the second option on my post should help you so long as you are just trying to add a button to the grid header (a toolbar). If you want a button in the first actual row in your grid an no others, then this i still not for you.

Comment: The toolbar option is close. I do want it in the header but I want it on the same row as "First Name", "Last Name","Title"

When I use the toolbar option, it places the button above the "First Name" etc...

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use headerTemplate for this 
check this working example

[dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/oWuju)

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
 columns: [{
     field: "name",
 }, {
     field: "FirstName",
     title: "First Name",
     width: "140px"
 }, {
     field: "LastName",
     title: "Last Name",
     width: "140px"
 }, {
     field: "Title",
     headerTemplate: 'Title <button id="foo" onclick="foo()">foo</button>'
 }],
 dataSource: [{
     name: "Jane Doe"
 }, {
     name: "John Doe"
 }]});
```

Comment: I know I can add it as html but then the function "foo()" has to be outside the grid. Which can be done, I was hoping to keep it all in the grid as this is part of a larger application.